# Discord.py More than 1 Int needed

Tags: python, embed, discord.py

Im trying to make a Spam command for my Discord Bot but i need more then 1 int so i cann set title description and spam amount... Would be nice if you cann help

```
@bot.command()
    async def spam(ctx, amount: int, title: int, *, message):
```

Error :
Converting to "int" failed for parameter "title".

Comment: Why are you trying to get title as integer?

Comment: I want do something like >spam 2 "That the Title" "This is the Description of the embed"

Comment: If you want the title `str`, why did you do `title: int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you set the title to Integer (Only accepts number), if you wan't it to be anything, just do this

```py
@bot.command()
async def spam(ctx, amount: int, title: str, *, message):
```

You probably need the title of a Embed, if you don't use embed, do this

```py
@bot.command()
   async def spam(ctx, amount: int, *, message):
```

Your code is trying to convert the title from String to Integer (That will raise a error).